# Display content from AJAX request using setState

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I'm doing a webapp using github search API. I want the info for each repo to be displayed under the specific repo.
I want the content from the AJAX request to be displayed when the specific button is being pressed. I am using React. Since I'm using item.x to access the information I need to get that item and I assume I need to use map but when doing that it will display all the results and not just the specific repository's. Anyway that I can get the Item since it currently says it's undefined?

```
let searchTerm;

class SearchBox extends React.Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { repositories: [],
        showInfo: false };

    }


    render() {
    let moreDetail;
    if(this.state.showInfo){
    moreDetail= <div className="info">                    <li>
                    <p>Open issue count </p>:{item.open_issues_count}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Number of forks </p>:{item.forks}
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <p>Language </p>:{item.language}
                    </li></div>;
    }
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <h2>Repositories</h2>
                <ul>
                { this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => (
                <div key={ index }>
                  <a href={item.html_url}>  <li >
                        { item.name }

                    </li>
                    </a>
                {moreDetail}

                    <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>Detailed view</button>
                </div>
                )) }
                </ul>
            </div>
            );
    }

    _handleClick(){
    this.setState({
    showInfo: !this.state.showInfo
    });
    }


    onClick(event) {

        searchTerm = this.searchBox.value;
        let endpoint = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?sort=stars&order=desc&q=' + searchTerm;
        console.log(searchTerm);
        fetch(endpoint)
            .then(blob => blob.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({ repositories: response.items });
            });
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with context. When you define the `moreDetail` variable, you don't have `item` in your context (only during the map function you have that.)

One option is to use the variable `moreDetail` as a function that receives the item you want to show.

Your render method should look something like:

```
render() {
    const moreDetail = (item) => ( !this.state.showInfo ? <span /> :
            <div className="info">                    
                <li>
                    <p>Open issue count </p>:{item.open_issues_count}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Number of forks </p>:{item.forks}
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p>Language </p>:{item.language}
                </li>
            </div>
        );

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
            <input type="text" className="searchbox"  ref={(input) => { this.searchBox = input; }}/>
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>Search</button>
            </form>
            <h2>Repositories</h2>
            <ul>
            { this.state.repositories.map( ( item, index ) => (
            <div key={ index }>
              <a href={item.html_url}>  <li >
                    { item.name }

                </li>
                </a>
                {moreDetail(item)}

                <button onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this)}>Detailed view</button>
            </div>
            )) }
            </ul>
        </div>
        );
}
```